# Is there a dark theme that supports Clojure on intellij?

Tags: clojure, intellij-idea

I have started using IntelliJ Idea for Clojure development.
I am struggling to find a good dark theme that supports Clojure.

I tried the dracula theme, isn't as good.

I am used to IR_BLACK on XCode for Objective-C bt couldn't find a similar theme for Clojure on Idea.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [IntelliJ Colors Solarized](https://github.com/jkaving/intellij-colors-solarized) theme?

But why the Dracula Theme isn't good for Clojure?

Personally I use VIM in JellyBeans theme for Clojure development.

Comment: I am using draculla theme as of now. will checkout Colors Solarized theme for Clojure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Borealis](https://github.com/Misophistful/borealis-cursive-theme), contributed by James Trunk.